# MKMapItem openMapsWithItems/openInmapsWithLaunchOptions address field and text of pin

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to change the text of address field (Header of the map), and keep the text of pin and text of address field differently for a MKMapItem?

I see the iOS native Contacts app is able to open the map with address field is the address of the contact, and the pin text is the contact name.

But when I open the iOS native map by calling

```
[MKMapItem openMapsWithItems/openInmapsWithLaunchOptions]
```

the text in address field and the text in pin are always the same. Why?

Answer (score 0):

```
[MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:mapItems launchOptions:nil];
```

needs an array a parameter:

```
//So you have to define:
 NSMutableArray* mapItems = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

//and now fill the array with MKMapItems
MKMapItem *mapItem = [[[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark] autorelease]; //placemark contains longitude and latitude values
[mapItem setName:@"This is my name"];
[mapItems addObject:mapItem];

//Now you can make the call:
[MKMapItem ope nMapsWithItems:mapItems launchOptions:nil];
```